# How to have dynamic template in angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a directive that be dynamic. In this directive define a template that have an input element. In fact this element `ng-model` must be dynamic, and use `$scope.name` in controller.

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
              name: '@',
              path:'@',
        },
        template: '<input\
             type="text"\
             name="{{name}}"\
             ng-model="{{name}}"\
              />\,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        },
        controller:{
          $scope.$watch($scope.name, function (newValue, oldValue) {
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: and what exactly is not working?

Comment: @Razvan Balosin this error apear in console : Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$parse/syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your directive syntax is wrong, here is the right one:

```
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        name: '@',
        path:'@',
      },
     template: '<input type="text" name="{{name}}" ng-model="name">',
     link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  
     },
     controller: function($scope) {
       $scope.name = 'asd';
       $scope.$watch('name', function (newValue, oldValue) {

       })
     }
  }
});
```

Secondly, if you are looking to have a dynamic `model`, you should use `scope: {name: '='}` as `@` is for one-time binding

#### edit

changed `name="name` in template to `name="{{name}}"`

#### And here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/F3NrrlcDt30B0M5vtrw2?p=preview)

Comment: for name attribute its work correctly but for ng-model not work :(

Comment: @hadi sorry, I had some typos as well in my answer, just updated it

Comment: @YonatanAyalon Ignoring the fact that you are just being rude here, the name was not updated because I forgot the `{{ }}`. Your case was just a very bad example, using another input to set the model

Comment: @YonatanAyalon also, spotting a small mistake in my answer and fixing it and making it your own answer it's not a good practice either..

Comment: @YonatanAyalon Moreover, your answer should contain `edits` showing what you've changed in your code, otherwise, all the comments and votes on your question wouldn't make any sense to others

Answer (score 0):

[A working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fixit/oywr1Lk8/5/)

**Code**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
   return {
   restrict: 'E',
scope: {
     name: '@',
     path:'@',
  },

   template: '<input type="text" name="{{name}}" ng-model="name"/> {{name}}',
 controller: function($scope) {
   $scope.name = "initial value";
   $scope.$watch('name', function (newValue, oldValue) {
       console.log("newValue: ",newValue);
   })
 }
```

}
});

Comment: This doesn't work, you had to create another input to set the model ;)

Comment: just edited and now the model is also being set from the directive